# ArrayAdapter Advice or Suggestions

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, gesture, prediction

I'm trying to figure out on how can I bind a selection of prediction on my Gesture. what I want in code is, I want my gesture stroke prediction binded on ArrayAdapter which show as a layout selection.

Unfortunately, I'm finding a way on this code which is not working. thanks guys in advance!

```
TextView edittext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = gLibrary.recognize(gesture);

adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, predictions);
edittext.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This is the current code I am using

```
@Override
public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
    AutoCompleteTextView edittext = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.myautocomplete);        
    ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = gLibrary.recognize(gesture); 

    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (predictions.size() > 0 && predictions.get(0).score > 1.0) {
        String result = predictions.get(0).name;
        edittext.setText(edittext.getText().toString() + result);
        }
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, al);
    edittext.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

> I want the result of prediction object list on adapter layout once the user put a gesture, so that, that way he/she may select the appropriate character. this code can recognize only a character not a word, if you have suggestion. pls. do so.. thanks guys!

```
goal:
once the user draw a gesture, register the stroke.
once the stroke already captured, use the gesture prediction library and bind it in adapter.
once the user input his gesture for example S, he/she may have the option to select the correct gesture character on selection that was bind on adapter.
```

Answer (score 0):

Once u have the Predictions rather than passing it pass create arraylist based on result.

**Code:**

```
ArrayList<String> al= new Arraylist<String>();

 if (predictions.size() > 0 && predictions.get(0).score > 1.0) {
        String result = predictions.get(0).name;

        if ("A".equalsIgnoreCase(result)) {
                    al.add(result);
            Toast.makeText(this, "A", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, al);
edittext.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Hi srikanth, thanks for that responce. but currently, what I want is that. once the gesture already predict the gesture stroke in textview the adapter will quickly suggest depending upon the Prediction pass on prediction object. I already tested and arrange your code.. tanks

Comment: the code doesn't work base on pass create arraylist based on result

Comment: I did something like this... Using GestureBuilder i used to create all possible gestures like (for S differnt possible combination) and verify based on result.I'm not sure how u will bind the But even if u bind the predictions how will u compare that ???

Comment: I already fix that. the problem was here in this line.

`    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();`


    `ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>(predictions);`

the only problem was that it return something like this


`The constructor ArrayList<String>(ArrayList<Prediction>) is undefined`

`2 quick fixes available
Remove the argument to match 'ArrayList<String>()' and
Change type of predictions to 'int'`

Comment: nice :) as i said i tried something like i've mentioned in the comment :)

Comment: do you have any solution on how can I bind the prediction to the adapter?

Comment: maybe you have an idea?.. better way of what I'm thinking